# Can't find my repo files after deploying to Azure App Service

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm very new to Azure App Service, but have started using it for my semester project. With Github Actions it gets automatically deployed and built on Azure and ready for me to test, and to share. I do have a slight problem finding all my repo files tho. I was hoping I could use the same relative paths I use in Visual Studio 2019, on Azure. But I can't seem to figure out where my images are running off to. I have a folder with image segments ment to be used in a puzzle game. Located in the "gamefiles" folder.

[image: Picture of my folder structure in VS2019]
[image: Picture of the folder structure in Azure App Service Editor]

Top picture is of my folder structure in VS2019 and the bottom picture is of the folder structure in Azure App Service Editor.
Do I need to use another Azure service to get all my files on there, or do I need to do something from Githubs side of things. Tried searching, but couldn't find anything that answer my question.. Any tips are greatly appriciated!

Comment: try changing the properties of the files 'Copy to Output Directory' to Copy Always or Copy if Newer.  Access Properties from the right click context menu.  I think you can select all the files to change all at one time.  Not positive this will fix but think it will.

Comment: seems to me the problem is that you have a wwwroot folder inside wwwroot folder (second pic). If you move the content from the child one to the parent one, your images should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below code in your `project_name.csproj` file.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="gamefiles\**">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

It should be useful to you.

---

## Test Steps

[image]

[image]

[image]